# Merge two arrays by multiple key value pairs

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays containing different stats of a user by main city and sub city.

The difference between two arrays is one having ofd property in it and other not having ofd. the other array having some other stats of same user like delivered.

So what i want to achieve here is to combine user stats into one array based on different main city and sub city...

Array 1:

```
[310] => Array
(
    [walker_id] => 158
    [walker] => سلطان 158
    [districts] => Al Muhammadiyah, Al Hamadaniyah, Abhur Aljanubiah, Al Basatin, Al Asalah, Ar Rayyan, Abur Ash Shamaliyah,
    Al Murjan, As Salhiyah, Al Khalidiyah, Ar Rawadah, Az Zahra, Al Faisaliyah, An Nahdah, Ash Shati, Al Wahah, Al
    Khaldiyah, Al Loaloa, Ar Rabwah, An Nuzhah, An Naim, King Abdul Aziz International Airport, Ash Sheraa, Az Zomorod, Al
    Yaqoot, Al Amwaj, Al Hamra, Al Andalus, Al Aziziyah, As Samir, Al Fadeylah, Al Waha, An Nakhil, Mraykh, Ash Sharafiyah,
    Al Marwah, Abhur Al Junoobiyah, Petoromin, An Nasim, Abrug Ar Rughamah, Al Amir Abdulmajed, Jeddah Islamic Seaport, Al
    Frosya, Taibah, As Salamah, As Sarawat, Al Farouk, Ar Rewis, As Safa, Ar Rawabi, Al Baghdadiyah Al Gharbiyah, Faysalia,
    Al Salamah, Mishrifah, Thuwal, Al Masarah
    [main_city] => Jeddah
    [sub_city] => Jeddah
    [ofd] => 25
)

[311] => Array
(
    [walker_id] => 158
    [walker] => سلطان 158
    [districts] => Al Muhammadiyah, Al Hamadaniyah, Abhur Aljanubiah, Al Basatin, Al Asalah, Ar Rayyan, Abur Ash Shamaliyah,
    Al Murjan, As Salhiyah, Al Khalidiyah, Ar Rawadah, Az Zahra, Al Faisaliyah, An Nahdah, Ash Shati, Al Wahah, Al
    Khaldiyah, Al Loaloa, Ar Rabwah, An Nuzhah, An Naim, King Abdul Aziz International Airport, Ash Sheraa, Az Zomorod, Al
    Yaqoot, Al Amwaj, Al Hamra, Al Andalus, Al Aziziyah, As Samir, Al Fadeylah, Al Waha, An Nakhil, Mraykh, Ash Sharafiyah,
    Al Marwah, Abhur Al Junoobiyah, Petoromin, An Nasim, Abrug Ar Rughamah, Al Amir Abdulmajed, Jeddah Islamic Seaport, Al
    Frosya, Taibah, As Salamah, As Sarawat, Al Farouk, Ar Rewis, As Safa, Ar Rawabi, Al Baghdadiyah Al Gharbiyah, Faysalia,
    Al Salamah, Mishrifah, Thuwal, Al Masarah
    [main_city] => Jeddah
    [sub_city] => Khulais
    [ofd] => 1
)
```

Array 2:

```
[260] => Array
(
    [walker_id] => 158
    [walker] => سلطان 158
    [main_city] => Jeddah
    [sub_city] => Jeddah
    [districts] => Al Muhammadiyah, Al Hamadaniyah, Abhur Aljanubiah, Al Basatin, Al Asalah, Ar Rayyan, Abur Ash Shamaliyah,
    Al Murjan, As Salhiyah, Al Khalidiyah, Ar Rawadah, Az Zahra, Al Faisaliyah, An Nahdah, Ash Shati, Al Wahah, Al
    Khaldiyah, Al Loaloa, Ar Rabwah, An Nuzhah, An Naim, King Abdul Aziz International Airport, Ash Sheraa, Az Zomorod, Al
    Yaqoot, Al Amwaj, Al Hamra, Al Andalus, Al Aziziyah, As Samir, Al Fadeylah, Al Waha, An Nakhil, Mraykh, Ash Sharafiyah,
    Al Marwah, Abhur Al Junoobiyah, Petoromin, An Nasim, Abrug Ar Rughamah, Al Amir Abdulmajed, Jeddah Islamic Seaport, Al
    Frosya, Taibah, As Salamah, As Sarawat, Al Farouk, Ar Rewis, As Safa, Ar Rawabi, Al Baghdadiyah Al Gharbiyah, Faysalia,
    Al Salamah, Mishrifah, Thuwal, Al Masarah
    [delivered] => 16
    [undelivered] => 3
    [returnedToowner] => 0
)

[261] => Array
(
    [walker_id] => 158
    [walker] => سلطان 158
    [main_city] => Jeddah
    [sub_city] => Khulais
    [districts] => Al Muhammadiyah, Al Hamadaniyah, Abhur Aljanubiah, Al Basatin, Al Asalah, Ar Rayyan, Abur Ash Shamaliyah,
    Al Murjan, As Salhiyah, Al Khalidiyah, Ar Rawadah, Az Zahra, Al Faisaliyah, An Nahdah, Ash Shati, Al Wahah, Al
    Khaldiyah, Al Loaloa, Ar Rabwah, An Nuzhah, An Naim, King Abdul Aziz International Airport, Ash Sheraa, Az Zomorod, Al
    Yaqoot, Al Amwaj, Al Hamra, Al Andalus, Al Aziziyah, As Samir, Al Fadeylah, Al Waha, An Nakhil, Mraykh, Ash Sharafiyah,
    Al Marwah, Abhur Al Junoobiyah, Petoromin, An Nasim, Abrug Ar Rughamah, Al Amir Abdulmajed, Jeddah Islamic Seaport, Al
    Frosya, Taibah, As Salamah, As Sarawat, Al Farouk, Ar Rewis, As Safa, Ar Rawabi, Al Baghdadiyah Al Gharbiyah, Faysalia,
    Al Salamah, Mishrifah, Thuwal, Al Masarah
    [delivered] => 0
    [undelivered] => 1
    [returnedToowner] => 0
```

Result Required:

```
[0] => Array
(
    [walker_id] => 158
    [walker] => سلطان 158
    [main_city] => Jeddah
    [sub_city] => Jeddah
    [districts] => Al Muhammadiyah, Al Hamadaniyah, Abhur Aljanubiah, Al Basatin, Al Asalah, Ar Rayyan, Abur Ash Shamaliyah,
    Al Murjan, As Salhiyah, Al Khalidiyah, Ar Rawadah, Az Zahra, Al Faisaliyah, An Nahdah, Ash Shati, Al Wahah, Al
    Khaldiyah, Al Loaloa, Ar Rabwah, An Nuzhah, An Naim, King Abdul Aziz International Airport, Ash Sheraa, Az Zomorod, Al
    Yaqoot, Al Amwaj, Al Hamra, Al Andalus, Al Aziziyah, As Samir, Al Fadeylah, Al Waha, An Nakhil, Mraykh, Ash Sharafiyah,
    Al Marwah, Abhur Al Junoobiyah, Petoromin, An Nasim, Abrug Ar Rughamah, Al Amir Abdulmajed, Jeddah Islamic Seaport, Al
    Frosya, Taibah, As Salamah, As Sarawat, Al Farouk, Ar Rewis, As Safa, Ar Rawabi, Al Baghdadiyah Al Gharbiyah, Faysalia,
    Al Salamah, Mishrifah, Thuwal, Al Masarah
    [delivered] => 16
    [undelivered] => 3
    [returnedToowner] => 0
    [ofd] => 53
)

[1] => Array
(
    [walker_id] => 158
    [walker] => سلطان 158
    [main_city] => Jeddah
    [sub_city] => Khulais
    [districts] => Al Muhammadiyah, Al Hamadaniyah, Abhur Aljanubiah, Al Basatin, Al Asalah, Ar Rayyan, Abur Ash Shamaliyah,
    Al Murjan, As Salhiyah, Al Khalidiyah, Ar Rawadah, Az Zahra, Al Faisaliyah, An Nahdah, Ash Shati, Al Wahah, Al
    Khaldiyah, Al Loaloa, Ar Rabwah, An Nuzhah, An Naim, King Abdul Aziz International Airport, Ash Sheraa, Az Zomorod, Al
    Yaqoot, Al Amwaj, Al Hamra, Al Andalus, Al Aziziyah, As Samir, Al Fadeylah, Al Waha, An Nakhil, Mraykh, Ash Sharafiyah,
    Al Marwah, Abhur Al Junoobiyah, Petoromin, An Nasim, Abrug Ar Rughamah, Al Amir Abdulmajed, Jeddah Islamic Seaport, Al
    Frosya, Taibah, As Salamah, As Sarawat, Al Farouk, Ar Rewis, As Safa, Ar Rawabi, Al Baghdadiyah Al Gharbiyah, Faysalia,
    Al Salamah, Mishrifah, Thuwal, Al Masarah
    [delivered] => 0
    [undelivered] => 1
    [returnedToowner] => 0
    [ofd]            => 1
```

Edit:

My code:

```
foreach($delivered as $value){

    $def[] = array(
        'walker_id' => $value->confirmed_walker,
        'walker'   => $value->walker,
        'main_city' => $value->main_city,
        'sub_city' => $value->d_city,
        'districts' => $value->districts,
        'delivered' => $value->delivered,
        'undelivered' => $value->undelivered,
        'returnedToowner' => $value->toowner,

    );
}


foreach($withCaptain as $value){
    $dataArray[] = array(
        'walker_id' => $value->walker_id,
        'walker'   => $value->walker,
        'districts' => $value->districts,
        'main_city' => $value->main_city,
        'sub_city' => $value->sub_city,
        'ofd'     => $value->ofd,
    );
}

$kv=[];
foreach($dataArray as $k => $v){
    $kv[ $v['walker_id'] ] = $k; // this is considering unique walker_id and not considering city and subcity

}

foreach($def as $k => $v){

    if(!isset($dataArray[$k]['delivered'])){
        $dataArray[$k]['delivered'] = 0;
        $dataArray[$k]['undelivered'] = 0;
    }

    if( array_key_exists( $v['walker_id'] , $kv ) ){      
        $dataArray[ $kv[$v['walker_id']] ] = array_merge( $dataArray[$kv[$v['walker_id']]] , $def[$k] );     
    }
}
```

want to combine $def and $dataArray. they both are non equal arrays.

so basically i want to combine both arrays based on walker_id,main_city and sub_city.

I have tried varies things but nothing is working out. i have tried this 
[Merge two associative arrays by same key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50587034/merge-two-associative-arrays-by-same-key)

But temp array does not consider main and sub cities and its just combing based on walker_id...

thanks in advance

Let me know if you need more details..

Comment: _“Let me know if you need more details..”_ - I think we might rather first of all need you to not ask this question over and over again … You asked about this several times already, and while you removed the previous versions now, all previous discussion, what people had to suggest you try, etc., is all lost now.

Comment: @04FS nothing is still suggested. i posted this as i didn't get a single answer to this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a simple approach:

```
<?php
$withOfd = [
  310 => [
    'walker_id' => 158,
    'walker' => "158 ??????????",
    'districts' => "...",
    'main_city' => "Jeddah",
    'sub_city' => "Jeddah",
    'ofd' => 25
  ],
  311 => [
    'walker_id' => 158,
    'walker' => "158 ??????????",
    'districts' => "...",
    'main_city' => "Jeddah",
    'sub_city' => "Khulais",
    'ofd' => 1
  ]
];

$withoutOfd = [
  260 => [
    'walker_id' => 158,
    'walker' => "158 ??????????",
    'main_city' => "Jeddah",
    'sub_city' => "Jeddah",
    'districts' => "...",
    'delivered' => 16,
    'undelivered' => 3,
    'returnedToowner' => 0
  ],
  261 => [
    'walker_id' => 158,
    'walker' => "158 ??????????",
    'main_city' => "Jeddah",
    'sub_city' => "Khulais",
    'districts' => "...",
    'delivered' => 0,
    'undelivered' => 1,
    'returnedToowner' => 0
  ]
];

$result = [];
array_walk($withOfd, function($with) use ($withoutOfd, &$result) {
  array_walk ($withoutOfd, function($without) use (&$result, $with) {
    if (   $with['walker_id'] == $without['walker_id']
        && $with['main_city'] == $without['main_city']
        && $with['sub_city']  == $without['sub_city']) {
      $result[] = array_merge($with, $without);
    }
  });
});
print_r($result);
```

The output obviously is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [walker_id] => 158
            [walker] => 158 ??????????
            [districts] => ...
            [main_city] => Jeddah
            [sub_city] => Jeddah
            [ofd] => 25
            [delivered] => 16
            [undelivered] => 3
            [returnedToowner] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [walker_id] => 158
            [walker] => 158 ??????????
            [districts] => ...
            [main_city] => Jeddah
            [sub_city] => Khulais
            [ofd] => 1
            [delivered] => 0
            [undelivered] => 1
            [returnedToowner] => 0
        )
)
```

UPDATE:

As a result of the comments and the discussion in the chat another variant which preserves entries in either array which do *not* have corresponding entries:

```
$result = [];
array_walk($withOfd, function($with, $withKey) use (&$withOfd, &$withoutOfd, &$result) {
  array_walk ($withoutOfd, function($without, $withoutKey) use (&$withOfd, &$withoutOfd, &$result, $with, $withKey) {
    if (   $with['walker_id'] == $without['walker_id']
        && $with['main_city'] == $without['main_city']
        && $with['sub_city']  == $without['sub_city']) {
      $result[] = array_merge($with, $without);
      unset($withOfd[$withKey]);
      unset($withoutOfd[$withoutKey]);
    }
  });
});
$result = array_merge($result, $withOfd, $withoutOfd);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but its giving me for only one main_city and sub_city... only for Jeddah and Jeddah.. result does not contain entry for Jeddah, Khulais... can you check if we are missing something ?

Comment: Sorry, but I completely fail to understand the issue. The result of that code contains _two_ entries, just as posted. One for Jeddah/Jeddah and one for Jeddah/Khulais. So I fail to understand what is missing here...

Comment: @rkascha: i added your snippet and printed out result it does not contain entries for jeddah/Khulais...

Comment: Then you have an issue with your output or maybe with your integration. I actually posted the output of that code with the answer. You can see that it contains two entries. Go, make a test, execute the code on a command line and see the result.

Comment: will this work for non equal arrays ? like my withofd array is greater than withoutofd array. so with ofd can have non existent walker_id in it.

Comment: You will easily be able to answer those questions yourself. You need to invest a bit of effort into actually _understanding_ the code you were given instead of just blindly copying it. You want to _learn_ how to program such stuff yourself, don't you?

Comment: yea you are right but from past 2 days i tried too many things and i am still learning a lot of things. i am still inspecting your code whats i am missing in it...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200013/discussion-between-danish-jamshed-and-arkascha).

Comment: I added an extended version of the algorithm itself as a result of your exchange.

Comment: Can you check if we are still missing something

Comment: I will have to check that later, it surprises me. The documentation explicitly states that this function will _not_ overwrite previous entries in case of numerical keys and indeed my test did _not_ show that behavior. Can you please prove example data? Thanks. (you can use the chat again...)